# how to place inline div and input

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a `html` `form`. There are many `input`'s and `label`'s. In the bottom of the `form` I have one `div` and one `input` (submit).

How can I place them (`div` and `input` (submit button)) in one horizontal line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left">my div</div><input type="submit" style="float:left">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.someclass {
  float: left;
  width: 200px /* or whatever you need to make it look good */
}
```

or **gross** inline styles with `<div style="float: left;"></div><input type="submit" />`

Answer (score 0):

Make both elements `float: left` and make their parent `overflow: auto`.

Mind sharing your code? It's a bit hard to do this blindly, as your HTML structure might be different that what I think it is.

Comment: `inline-block` isn't supported by IE, so I typically try to stray away.

Comment: I agree.  It would make life so much easier especially for nav elements, too bad IE has to ruin the internet. ;P

Comment: Inline-block works in IE for elements that are originally inline... like `label`, `span`, etc.

Comment: @ANeves, that's because IE doesn't apply `inline-block` to them. They just stay `inline`.

Comment: @Blender, if it was as you say, then in IE7 all the lines in this example should look the same, which is not the case: http://jsfiddle.net/wPZwL/3/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to target input types specifically, like:

`input [type=submit] { css rules here }`

So you could just assign your `div` to `float:left;` and do the same with your `input`. Floating them will cause them to line up next to each other.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwXC5/)